# Why pdf in iframe does not scale horizontally If iframe's width is more than 900px?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe, webkit

This problem exists for webkit browsers only chrome and possibly safari (i've not tested it in). As you can the demo below, you will see the extra space on left and right side of pdf file loaded within an iframe.

http://jsfiddle.net/wG49Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that happens when a pdf is rendered by the chrome's default pdf viewer. You can resolve this issue If disable the default pdf viewer and install the new pdf viewer like adobe acrobat. You can disable the default viewer by going to `about:plugins' in the browser tab and click the disable link shown below 'Chrome PDF Viewer'.

Answer (score 0):

That is because PDF files are rendered by browser-specific plugins in Safari and Chrome. It looks like the browser simply picks the zoom level for the document as last used by the user.

Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a way to influence the display parameters from a web page to e.g. increase the zoom level.